# Xamarin iOS UIButton image not showing on device when testing

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, uibutton, testflight

I am currently testing my xamarin iOS app on TestFlight with an iOS device. The app is running fine but the images in my UIButtons arent showing up at all.

Heres my button code:

```
    _uiAttributes.myScheduleImage = UIImage.FromFile("images/myschedule.PNG");
                _uiAttributes.myCareersImage = UIImage.FromFile("images/mycareer.PNG");
                _uiAttributes.mySocialImage = UIImage.FromFile("images/mysocial.PNG");
                _uiAttributes.FeedbackImage = UIImage.FromFile("images/feedback.PNG");
                _uiAttributes.myDetailsImage = UIImage.FromFile("images/mydetails.PNG");

buttonList = new List<UIButton>
            {
                _uiControls.btn_MySchedule,
                _uiControls.btn_MyCareer,
                _uiControls.btn_MySocial,
                _uiControls.btn_Feedback,
                _uiControls.btn_MyDetails
            };

buttonImageList = new List<UIImage>
            {
                _uiAttributes.myScheduleImage,
                _uiAttributes.myCareersImage,
                _uiAttributes.mySocialImage,
                _uiAttributes.feedbackImage,
                _uiAttributes.myDetailsImage
            };
```

I pass this code through to a Draw method.

```
public void DrawImageButton(List<UIButton> buttonList, List<CGRect> buttonDimensionsList, List<UIImage> buttonImageList, UIView container)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
            {
                buttonList[i].Frame = buttonDimensionsList[i];
                buttonList[i].SetImage(buttonImageList[i], UIControlState.Normal);

                container.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins;
                buttonList[i].AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;

                container.AddSubview(buttonList[i]);
            }
        }
```

The buttons are showing up when i run it on a simulator but not my actual device.

I will attach an screenshot of my images below:
[Resources/images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX3dm.png)

I have checked a number of related answers but theyre all in Xcode. I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 to develop my application.

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Remove "images/" from path and check. Like  UIImage.FromFile("myschedule.PNG");

Comment: @Apurv I have just done that but now they wont even show up on the simulator?

Comment: be sure your casing is correct on your path and file names.  The simulator is more forgiving about casing than the actual device.

Comment: Check the path of the image and check package content of your binary. If any component is missing then add.

Comment: I have tested the app on an iOS Device again and the images still aren't showing up. Due to the images being held in the "images" folder within the "Resources" directory would i have to keep the line `UIImage.FromFile("images/myschedule.PNG");` instead of changing it to `UIImage.FromFile("myschedule.PNG");`

Comment: Also would i have to create different versions of the image, such as "image.png", "image@2x.png", "image@3x.png" even though all the images are just 100x100? Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So I have managed to fix this issue. The problem was that i never changed the Copy to Output Directory to "Copy Always" in the properties panel for each image. Also I had to state the path of the image being loaded.

```
_uiAttributes.myScheduleImage = UIImage.FromFile("images/myschedule.PNG");
```

Thanks for all the help!